# Build non-decreasing $f$,$g$ from $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb N$ such that $f$ is not $O(g)$ and $g$ is not $O(f)$

Tags: computational-complexity, natural-numbers

Show that there exist non-decreasing  $f,g:\Bbb N\to \Bbb N$ such that $f\neq O(g)$ and $g\neq O(f)$. ($\Bbb N$ is the set of strictly positive integers.)

Source: Victor Shoup's "A computational introduction to number theory and algebra".

Also, I'd be interested if this also holds for increasing functions as well.

Note: I tried building the functions such that each of them has an exponential subsequence that is linear in the other.. no success. Would this be doable?

Comment: Your idea in the note is in the right direction.  You need to have $f \gg g$, then $g \gg f$, alternating infinitely.  You need to make sure the ratio between them at its highest is unbounded.

Comment: Thank you. I, however, am unsure how to do it because of the non-decreasing requirement. It's pretty sad I actually think I might have found a solution to this problem a year ago or so, but I can't find it anymore.

Comment: See [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/135953/125618).

Comment: Just have one of them grow slowly while the other grows quickly.  Then when the second has gotten enough larger than the first, let it grow slowly while the first grows quickly.  If you have an approach that is not increasing, just boost up the portions that decrease and you are there.

Comment: @RossMillikan Thank you, I will try, but I'm not sure I can manage. I would love to know what you actually have in mind.

Comment: @plop I will give it a look. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every $n\ge 1$, let $k(n)$ be such that $2^{k(n)}\le n< 2^{k(n)+1}$. The point of this definition is that we can write $\mathbb N_+$ as an "interleaving"
$$
\mathbb N_+ = \bigcup_{k\ \text{even}}[2^k,2^{k+1})\cup\bigcup_{k\ \text{odd}}[2^k,2^{k+1}).
$$
Define
$$
f(n) = \begin{cases} n^{k(n)+1} & \text{if $k(n)$ is even}\\ n^{k(n)} & \text{if $k(n)$ is odd}\end{cases}\quad\text{and}\quad g(n) = \begin{cases} n^{k(n)} & \text{if $k(n)$ is even}\\ n^{k(n)+1} & \text{if $k(n)$ is odd}\end{cases}.
$$
Here is a table of the values of $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ that hopefully makes it clear at a glance that $f$ and $g$ are increasing, though I added a proof at the end of the post, too.
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
k(n)& 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & \dots\\ \hline
 f(n)& n^1& n^1& n^3 & n^3 & n^5 & n^5 & n^7 & n^7 & \dots\\ \hline
 g(n)& n^0 & n^2 & n^2 & n^4 & n^4 & n^6 & n^6 & n^8 & \dots\\ \hline
\end{array}
The point of this definition is that we have:
$$
\frac{f(n)}{g(n)} = \begin{cases}n & \text{if $k(n)$ is even}\\n^{-1} & \text{if $k(n)$ is odd} \end{cases}.
$$
This shows that $f \ne O(g)$ and $g \ne O(f)$.

---

**Proof that $f$ and $g$ are increasing.** Clearly $f$ and $g$ are increasing for $n$ in any of the intervals of the form $[2^b,2^{b+1})$, so we only need to check $f(2^{b}-1)< f(2^{b})$, and similarly for $g$. Since $2^{b-1}\le 2^b-1 < 2^b$, $$k(2^b-1) = b-1\quad\text{and}\quad k(2^b) = b.$$

If $b$ is even, $b-1$ is odd, so
$$
f(2^b-1) = (2^b-1)^{b-1} < (2^b)^{b+1} = f(2^b).
$$
If $b$ is odd, $b-1$ is even, so
$$
f(2^b-1) = (2^b-1)^{b} < (2^b)^b = f(2^b).
$$
This shows that $f$ is increasing. An analogous argument shows $g(2^b-1)< g(2^b)$. $\square$

Comment: That is awesome! Thank you, beautiful explanation.

Comment: @PhantomR: Happy it helps! :-)